# Using the same cable for HDD and SSD

Tags: mac, hard-drive, ssd, cable

I would like to know if is it possible (compatible) to use the same cable of a 3.5" HDD for a 2.5" SSD, or in other words, just swap one for another?

Comment: Question is very vague. Please update it to reflect what kind of cable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. However, going from a 2.5 to a 3.5 if you're using a laptop will not work, because a 3.5" won't fit.

*NOTE Make sure both connections are SATA or IDE. If they are not, then they are not compatible. The picture shows the difference between the two.

[image: SATA vs. IDE]
<sup>**Source**: [www.LaptopParts101.com](http://www.laptopparts101.com)</sup>

Comment: My motherboard came with two cables, each designated for either SATA II or SATA III. Are the two cables actually different and would that influence the decision of OP?

Comment: To my knowledge a SATA cable is a SATA cable (the pinouts are no different).  I guess cheap ones might not be able to handle the throughput of SATA III without interference though.

Comment: @Shinrai Yeah I wasn't sure, just thought I'd check.

Comment: Yes these cables are the same, as @Shinrai said the only problem may be the amount of data transfer these can handle. However, unless you have a SSD, this won't matter. SSD's are the only hardware that can fully utilize SATA III

Comment: This shows an IDE drive.  Just FYI, 3.5" and 2.5" IDE's use different size connectors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and compatible. If both the SSD and HDD, (no matter the size) have the same interface, which is probably SATA in your case.
In fact the cable it self does not matter that much. All SATA cables revision I, II, and III are identical and would work for all SATA devices.